# NSDictionary lookups with +valueWithPointer: keys are too slow

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c++

I have an Objective C++ class, instances of which are required to store an arbitrary set of C++ objects and associate each with a corresponding Objective C object.  Looking up the Objective C objects when given the C++ object is killing my performance, so I'm looking for a better solution.

I'm currently storing the pairs in an NSMutableDictionary after creating the keys using [NSValue valueWithPointer:].  The lookup time, in which +valueWithPointer: is about twice as expensive as -objectForKey:, is simply too slow.

The C++ objects are in a third-party framework, and do not provide any unique identifier.

The sets of C++ objects are always smaller than a dozen elements.

What is a faster approach to performing these lookups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three approaches that seem worth trying:

1. Use NSMapTable
2. Use objc_setAssociatedObject
3. Use std::unordered_map or std::map

objc_setAssociatedObject uses std::unordered_map behind the scenes.

Comment: NSMapTable is iOS 6+, so it won't work for this app.  objc_setAssociatedObject has its uses, but in this case I would feel a bit hackish using it.  std::unordered_map works wonderfully - 10x boost in speed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with `[NSValue valueWithNonRetainedObject:]` being too slow.

The solution I went with was to drop down a level and use CoreFoundation's CFMutableDictionary. I would suggest you take a look at it: [CFMutableDictionary Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html). It takes regular C pointers in `CFDictionaryAddValue()`, `CFDictionaryRemoveValue`, so it's the best thing to use to interface Obj-C and C++ (C is their common denominator).

The reason I'd rather do that than use an `std::unordered_map` is because I tend to want to minimise C++ in these kind of things. Obj-C++ is a bit of a hack and it's best to just reduce it to glue code between real Obj-C and existing C++ code.